# Cannot Surf the Web Through Chromium

Tags: networking, ethernet, web-browsers

It's weird, I can reach `google.com`, perform a search and see the results, pull up Gmail, I can go to `raspberrypi.org`, but anything past that I cannot reach.

In the Terminal I cannot `ping google.com`.  "Network is unreachable"
I can ping 127.0.0.1

The kernel IP routing Table returns

```
Destination   Gateway  Genmask       Flags Metric Ref  Use Iface
192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0   U     202   0    0   eth0
```

I know the default gateway is 192.168.1.254 and have tried adding it to the table but it did not fix the issue. I am able to ping the default gateway and have been issued an IP address.

I've tried changing the `interfaces` file to read:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's in your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I think I figured out my issue.   I realized that after downloading NOOBS, I failed to unzip the file and just copied over the contents.  I think something did not decompress.   I wiped the SD card and reloaded the files.   Then re-imaged the Raspberry Pi and viola everything works now.

Comment: In that case you should do one of two things, either delete your question or answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I re-imaged the RaspberryPi to the default setup. This cleared up the issue.

Since this was a brand new install it seems as if some of the file may have been corrupt on the initial install.   It was easier to reimage than to deep troubleshoot.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.